# Python abstract class with abstract properties and methods

Tags: python, abstract-class

I need to create an abstract base class, and a couple of child classes that inherits from it, implementating all of its methods and properties.

This is what I tried so far:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod, abstractproperty

class Cypher(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    
    @abstractproperty
    def _name(self): pass
    @abstractproperty
    def alphabet(self): pass
    @abstractproperty
    def password(self): pass

    @abstractmethod
    def getName(self): pass
    @abstractmethod
    def getAlphabet(self): pass
    @abstractmethod
    def getPass(self): pass
    #ENCRYPT-DECRYPT------------------------------------------------------
    @abstractmethod
    def encryptLine(self,plain_input): pass
```

and being a child class:

```
class Caesar(Cypher):
 
    def __init__(self,name,alphabet,password):
        self._name      =   name
        self.alphabet   =   alphabet
        self.password   =   password
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    def getName(self):      return self._name
    def getAlphabet(self):  return self.alphabet
    def getPass(self):      return self.password

    def encryptLine(self,plain_input):
        output=""
        #do stuff
        return output;
```

but whenever I try to instatiate a Caesar object, I get:

```
 self._name = name
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, *don't write getters and setters in Python*.

Comment: Please read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta` is *not* how you set a metaclass in Python 3, you need `class Cypher(object, metaclass=ABCMeta): ...`

Comment: In any case, that will still give you an error, because you *never implemented the `property` in your child class*

Comment: Also note https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty - you're using it incorrectly, and it's deprecated anyway.

Comment: But seriously, *Python is not Java*. Stop trying to write a Python class like a Java bean

Comment: Voted to re-open, the linked duplicate does not apply here, it seems to be talking about Python 2, but the OP is writing `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta` but that isn't how you use a metalass in Python 2, and even if you do use a metaclass correctly,  OP's concrete class would still fail upon instantiation

Comment: I'm actually trying to implement this on python3. Maybe I messed up things :S

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't see how this is *not* a duplicate. The core issue is exactly the same: an `abstractproperty` not being implemented in the class... The answer applies here just the same (tested on Python 3)

Comment: @Tomerikoo ah, you are right, but we should really clarify that the answer to that question will only work on Python 2 using `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sadly (to myself), I'm not so fluent with metaclasses, but I ran the exact same code with Python 3 (with the `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta`) and it seemed to work fine...

Comment: @Tomerikoo it doesn't, you haven't actually used the metaclass

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah right. Makes sense. The line has no effect... Is it even needed when using the `abstractmethod` decorator?

Comment: @Tomerikoo No, but you *definitely* need to use `class Cypher(metaclass=ABCMeta): ...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. Please see my edit on the accepted in the dupe target. I believe it covers pretty much everything discussed here